# iOS Swift App - Display a Wiki Page

Tags: swift, format, wiki

I need to display Wiki formatted pages in iOS, so they look correct.
I can't find anywhere to help. 
Perhaps there is a formatter to convert Wiki format to html.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: Wiki formatted pages means ? which controll are you using to display ?

Comment: Maybe try to display them using UIWebView (it's an UI element you can drag and drop in storyboard). Or eventually you could use WKWebView, which offers some advantages over UIWebView.

Comment: Thanks. I am displaying using UIWebView, but I want it displayed "nicely". UIWebView does nothing with the Wiki formatting commands. What I want is something that converts them to html, so the pages can be viewed correctly (there is a plugin in Android that does this, I was wondering if there is something similar inSwift / iOS).